# Add a property without instance variable?

Tags: objective-c, properties

I'm trying to add a property without creating an instance variable. Is it possible to do this? Or can you do something similar in a way that's not a property?

Example:

```
@interface RandomClass()
@property (nonatomic) int value;
@end

@implementation RandomClass
@synthesize value = _value;
// Here I override the default methods @synthesize
-(int)value
{
      return 8; // Actually I'm returning something more complex, so a "define" won't work
}
-(void)setValue:(int)value
{
   self.someOtherValue = value;
}
```

In the code above, I'm not using the instance variable `_value`! Is there a way to do this without creating the variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the line

```
@synthesize value = _value;
```

Since you're implementing the getter/setter yourself, the `@synthesize` isn't helpful.

---

`@synthesize` serves two jobs. The first job is to connect the property to a backing ivar, synthesizing the ivar if it doesn't already exist. The second job is to synthesize the getter/setter. If you don't need the backing ivar, and if you're providing implementations for the getter/setter yourself, then you don't need the `@synthesize` at all.

Comment: If you are going to declare a property, regardless of it being backed by a declared ivar or not, you should have either a `@synthesize` or `@dynamic` declaration for it. The OP probably have an `@dynamic` declaration. And in that case, and given what his comments say in the code, he probably doesn't need the declared ivar either.

Comment: @claireware: On the contrary, if the compiler can see that the methods are implemented, there's no need for `@dynamic`. See ["Property Implementation Directives"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW9): <quote>You can use the `@synthesize` and `@dynamic` directives in `@implementation` blocks to trigger specific compiler actions. Note that neither is required for any given `@property` declaration.</quote>

Comment: @claireware: Josh is correct. `@dynamic` tells the compiler not to worry if it can't find the getter/setter because they will be provided at runtime. If you are intending on providing the getter/setter at *compile* time, then you don't need `@dynamic` (in fact, better to not have it, because then the compiler will yell at you if you manage to forget to implement the getter or setter).

Comment: Kevin, Claire, Jacques — thank you, all three of you — this helped me a lot. Took me reading several posts about this before I finally found this answer here.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Doesn't the compiler still create an ivar tho if you have `@property propertyName` even if you provide your own setter/getters?

Comment: @LightningStryk: It does not, although I expected it to with automatic synthesis. If either a setter or a getter is defined, the ivar will be created automatically (with an underscore prefix), but not if both are. It _definitely_ did not create the ivar at the time this answer and comments were written.

Comment: @LightningStryk: The compiler will create the ivar if and only if it synthesizes. Auto-synthesis does not happen if you implement both methods. It will happen if you omit either the getter or the setter (assuming a readwrite property). If you have a `@synthesize` line you are explicitly telling the compiler to synthesize the ivar even if you implemented both the getter/setter.

Comment: Any idea how to remove the backing variable in new versions of Xcode where the compiler auto synthesizes the backing variable?

Comment: @rounak If you implement the getter/setter manually, no ivar is synthesized. The ivar is only synthesized if you explicitly write the `@synthesize` or if you let Xcode auto-synthesize the getter or setter.

Comment: @KevinBallard ah, so you mean if I implement both setter and getter, Xcode won't automatically create a backing ivar? Awesome.